# How can I test functions polymorphic over Applicatives?

Tags: haskell, applicative, quickcheck

I've just [written a function](https://github.com/haskell/containers/pull/179) (for `Data.Sequence`)

```
traverseWithIndex :: Applicative f => (Int -> a -> f b) -> Seq a -> f (Seq b)
```

which should obey

```
traverseWithIndex f = sequenceA . mapWithIndex f
```

Thankfully, this is a straightforward mechanical modification of the source of `mapWithIndex`, so I am quite confident it is correct. However, in more complex cases thorough testing would be required. I'm trying to write a QuickCheck property to test this simple one. Obviously, I can't try it out with every `Applicative` functor! When testing monoids, it makes good sense to test with the free monoid over (i.e., finite lists of) some type. So it seems sensible here to test with the [free applicative functor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/Control-Applicative-Free.html) over some functor. There are two difficulties:

1. How do I choose an appropriate base functor? I presumably want a nasty one that isn't applicative or traversable or anything, but such a thing seems likely hard to work with.
2. How do I compare the results? They'll have functions in them, so they have no `Eq` instance.

Answer (score 2):

> Obviously, I can't try it out with every `Applicative` functor!

I'm reminded of this blog post series, which I won't claim to fully understand:

- http://comonad.com/reader/2012/abstracting-with-applicatives/
- http://comonad.com/reader/2013/algebras-of-applicatives/

The lesson that I recall drawing from this is that nearly every applicative functor you see in the wild turns out to be the composition, product or (restricted) coproduct of simpler ones like these (not meant to be exhaustive):

1. `Const`
2. `Identity`
3. `(->)`

So while you can't try it out with every `Applicative` functor, there are inductive arguments that you might be able to exploit in QuickCheck properties to gain confidence that your function works for large inductively-defined families of functors.  So for example you could test:

- Your function works correctly for the "atomic" applicatives of your choice;
- If your function works correctly for functors `f` and `g`, it works correctly for `Compose f g`, `Product f g` and `Coproduct f g`.

> How do I compare the results? They'll have functions in them, so they have no `Eq` instance.

Well, I think you may have to look at QuickCheck testing of function equality.  Last time I had to do something along those lines I went with Conal's [`checkers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers) library, which has [an `EqProp` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers-0.4.4/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Checkers.html#t:EqProp) for "[t]ypes of values that can be tested for equality, perhaps through random sampling."  This should give you an idea already—even if you don't have an `Eq` instance for functions, `QuickCheck` may be capable of proving that two functions are unequal.  Critically, this instance exists:

```
instance (Show a, Arbitrary a, EqProp b) => EqProp (a -> b)
```

...and any type that has an `Eq` instance has a trivial `EqProp` instance where `(=-=) = (==)`.

So that suggests, to my mind, using `Coyoneda Something` as the base functor, and figuring out how to plug together all the little functions.

Comment: Ooh, things to read. I'll have to try tomorrow! This algebraic approach does sound promising.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a partial(?) solution.  The main aspects we want to check are 1) obviously the same value is computed, and 2) the effects are performed in the same order.  I think the following code is self-explanatory enough:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
module Main where
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Applicative.Free
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Test.QuickCheck
import Text.Show.Functions -- for Show instance for function types

data Fork a = F a | G a deriving (Eq, Show)

toIdentity :: Fork a -> Identity a
toIdentity (F a) = Identity a
toIdentity (G a) = Identity a

instance Functor Fork where
    fmap f (F a) = F (f a)
    fmap f (G a) = G (f a)

instance (Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (Fork a) where
    arbitrary = elements [F,G] <*> arbitrary

instance (Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (Ap Fork a) where
    arbitrary = oneof [Pure <$> arbitrary, 
                       Ap <$> (arbitrary :: Gen (Fork Int)) <*> arbitrary]

effectOrder :: Ap Fork a -> [Fork ()]
effectOrder (Pure _) = []
effectOrder (Ap x f) = fmap (const ()) x : effectOrder f

value :: Ap Fork a -> a
value = runIdentity . runAp toIdentity

checkApplicative :: (Eq a) => Ap Fork a -> Ap Fork a -> Bool
checkApplicative x y = effectOrder x == effectOrder y && value x == value y

succeedingExample = quickCheck (\f x -> checkApplicative 
    (traverse (f :: Int -> Ap Fork Int) (x :: [Int])) 
    (sequenceA (fmap f x)))

-- note reverse
failingExample = quickCheck (\f x -> checkApplicative 
    (traverse (f :: Int -> Ap Fork Int) (reverse x :: [Int])) 
    (sequenceA (fmap f x)))

-- instance just for example, could make a more informative one
instance Show (Ap Fork Int) where show _ = "<Ap>"

-- values match ...
betterSucceedingExample = quickCheck (\x -> 
    value (sequenceA (x :: [Ap Fork Int])) 
 == value (fmap reverse (sequenceA (reverse x))))

-- but effects don't.
betterFailingExample = quickCheck (\x -> checkApplicative 
    (sequenceA (x :: [Ap Fork Int])) 
    (fmap reverse (sequenceA (reverse x))))
```

The output looks like:

```
*Main Text.Show.Functions> succeedingExample             
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.                                
*Main Text.Show.Functions> failingExample                
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 3 tests and 2 shrinks):   
<function>                                               
[0,1]               
*Main Text.Show.Functions> betterSucceedingExample
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
*Main Text.Show.Functions> betterFailingExample
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 10 tests and 1 shrink):
[<Ap>,<Ap>]
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. Does `Fork` offer anything over `Either` here?

Comment: It has a different kind than `Either`.  That said, you could do `data Labeled a = Labeled String a` instead of `Fork` with the obvious(?) arbitrary instance.  Technically, I don't believe this would increase the discriminatory power but it may make counter-examples easier to find for QuickCheck (though I think only rarely).

Comment: Ah, I missed that rather blatant distinction.